# Problems with references using variable number of std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdthread

I have use posix threads (pthread) but I am giving a try to standard C++11 thread (which most likely is also pthread underneath). I have gone several posts here and other forums but I could not figure out my problem. I would love if someone can give a light.

The problem is that I am trying to pass data to threads, that modify the data inside and the modification must be seen by the main thread after the thrown threads are finished (joined). The problem is that in some threads the data (an int) is not read correctly, thus the output result is not correct.

The minimal code I could write to replicate the problem is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void threadCallbackInt(int const & x)
{
    int & y = const_cast<int &>(x);
    y += 10;
    std::cout<<"Inside Thread x = "<<y << " at position = " << &y <<std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    unsigned int nthreads = 3;
    vector<int> ints;
    vector<std::thread> threads(nthreads);
    threads.reserve(nthreads);
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < nthreads; i++){
        ints.push_back(i);

        std::cout<<"In Main Thread : Before Thread Start x = "<<ints.at(i)<< " at position = " << &ints.at(i) << std::endl;
        threads[i] = std::thread(threadCallbackInt,std::ref(ints[i]));
    }

    cout << "size = " << threads.size() << endl;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < nthreads; i++){
        threads[i].join();
    }

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < nthreads; i++){
        std::cout<<"In Main Thread : After Thread Start x = "<<ints[i]<< " at position = " << &ints[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There are several similar posts over several forums, but the one that I think that is the closet to my problem is the one at [C++ 11 std::thread strange behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732003/c-11-stdthread-strange-behavior)

Note that I use the method reserve in order to avoid reference invalidation and the number, but with no avail.

Depend on the execution, I get different outputs. This is one of the outputs:

> In Main Thread : Before Thread Start x = 0 at position = 0x21d7c40
>
> In Main Thread : Before Thread Start x = 1 at position = 0x21d81e4
>
> In Main Thread : Before Thread Start x = 2 at position = 0x21d7c48
>
> Inside Thread x = 10 at position = 0x21d81e4
>
> size = 3
>
> Inside Thread x = 12 at position = 0x21d7c48
>
> Inside Thread x = 10 at position = 0x21d7c40
>
> In Main Thread : After Thread Start x = 10 at position = 0x21d7c40
>
> In Main Thread : After Thread Start x = 1 at position = 0x21d7c44
>
> In Main Thread : After Thread Start x = 12 at position = 0x21d7c48

Note that one of the x's is still not updated, even after the thread is finished. This is because the memory that was used for that is not the correct one (before the thread it is 0x21d81e4, and after it is 0x21d7c40). If you run the code, you will see that the results ill be different, and any time that a reference mismatch, I get the wrong result.

Any light regarding a possible solution will be very welcome. Sorry if this post is duplicate (I could not find a actual answer for this exact problem). But if it is, please, indicate the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The address of a[0] is changing after executing ints.push_back(i). 
With adding `std::cout << "ints.size()=" << ints.size() << " &ints[0]=" << &ints[0] << endl;` before printing 'In Main Thread...' , the output is as follow (I am testing the code with Visual Studio 2017 and added EnterCriticalSection/LeaveCriticalSection to make the output not mixed up.)

```
ints.size()=1 &ints[0]=0095BA28
In Main Thread : Before Thread Start x = 0 at position = 0095BA28
Inside Thread x = 10 at position = 0095BA28
ints.size()=2 &ints[0]=0095BA38
In Main Thread : Before Thread Start x = 1 at position = 0095BA3C
Inside Thread x = 11 at position = 0095BA3C
ints.size()=3 &ints[0]=0095E940
In Main Thread : Before Thread Start x = 2 at position = 0095E948
Inside Thread x = 12 at position = 0095E948
size = 3
In Main Thread : After Thread Start x = 10 at position = 0095E940
In Main Thread : After Thread Start x = 11 at position = 0095E944
In Main Thread : After Thread Start x = 12 at position = 0095E948
```

The vector object is resized and int[0] points to the newly allocated object. 
So adding `ints.reserve(nthreads);` makes the pointers to the ints vector preserved.

```
ints.size()=1 &ints[0]=00DD8608
In Main Thread : Before Thread Start x = 0 at position = 00DD8608
Inside Thread x = 10 at position = 00DD8608
ints.size()=2 &ints[0]=00DD8608
In Main Thread : Before Thread Start x = 1 at position = 00DD860C
Inside Thread x = 11 at position = 00DD860C
ints.size()=3 &ints[0]=00DD8608
In Main Thread : Before Thread Start x = 2 at position = 00DD8610
Inside Thread x = 12 at position = 00DD8610
size = 3
In Main Thread : After Thread Start x = 10 at position = 00DD8608
In Main Thread : After Thread Start x = 11 at position = 00DD860C
In Main Thread : After Thread Start x = 12 at position = 00DD8610
```

Comment: Many thanks man!!! Now it works! You know, I was focusing on having the reserve() for the vector of threads, but I forgot about the vector of ints. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The reference `std::ref(ints[i])` is invalidated when `ints` is resized by `ints.push_back(i);`. If you wish to do it this way, you need to use `reserve` on `ints` as well.

In testing with gcc,

- When `i == 0`, then `ints.capacity() == 1`
- When `i == 1`, then `ints.capacity() == 2`
- When `i == 2`, then `ints.capacity() == 4`

Which shows that a resize is indeed happening.

Comment: "The completion of the thread represented by `*this` synchronizes with (1.10) the corresponding successful `join()` return" - The standard guarantees that all changes made by a thread are visible by the time `join` returns.

Comment: thanks -- I am very cautious about accessing non-mutex guarded non-atomic other-thread modified data in C++ because of how easy it is to generate UB.

Comment: Many thanks Falcon! Now it works just fine! I was focusing on the vector of threads and putting the reserve() for that vector, but I was forgetting about the vector ints. Many thanks.